# FormFunction default display

Tags: form-building

I am trying to use `FormFunction[]` to input data in my notebook.
As it shows up when using `FormFunction` in a notebook (no web deploy)
no default values are displayed (even if specified) only empty input fields although the defaults are returned correctly when accepting the Form.

[image]

Bug or feature ?
Is there any option to enable the initial display of default values?

Meanwhile I came up with the following solution:

---

```
FormFunctionInit[l_, "Init" -> True] :=  
 FormFunction[FormObject[l][Cases[l, (a_ -> b_ -> c_) :> (a -> c)]]]  

FormFunctionInit[l_, ___] :=
 FormFunction[FormObject[l][]]

form = FormFunctionInit[
   {  
    "x1" -> "Number" -> 1,  
    "x2" -> "Number" -> 2,  
    "x3" -> "Number",  
    "x4" -> "Number" -> 4  
    }, "Init" -> True  
   ];

input = form[] // Normal
```

[image]

> out[[3]]= {x1->1, x2->2, x3->55, x4->4}

---

Any suggestions for improvement avoiding my custom code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are most likely looking for the `Input` format. In the [Details and Options section of `FormFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html) it specifies that you can have this form

> FormFunction[formspec,func][<|"namek"->inputk,…|>]
>
> inserts the inputs given into the form specified by FormFunction before evaluating the effect of the FormFunction.

```
  FormFunction[{
     "x1" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Number", "Input" -> 1|>,
     "x2" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Number", "Input" -> 2|>,
     "x3" -> "Number",
     "x4" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Number", "Input" -> 4|>}][]
```

[image]

**Notice**: If you complete x3 field e.g. with number 3 then it returns the default (input) values for x1,x2,x3. In that case there is no need for a "Default". I am not sure though how these two are contrasted.

```
  Out= <|"x1" -> 1, "x2" -> 2, "x3" -> 3, "x4" -> 4|>
```